# bind(this)とは

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

React.jsのチュートリアル(https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)をやっていた所、以下のようなコードが出てきました。

```
// tutorial13.js
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

ここのbind(this)とは、どういった意味なのでしょうか

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: コメント、ありがとうございます。
 success: function (data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }
だけだとthisがwindowオブジェクトになってしまうということでしょうか？

Comment: `this`がReact.jsのコンポーネントです。チュートリアルでも説明されています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。理解出来ました！

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

の例に、ドンピシャに書いてありました。